# Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyProjectName' - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget

I'm developing a UWP app with visual studio 2017 on a computer without internet connection.

**My question:**
How can I install a packages on a UWP app without using the internet?

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to install a package offline via nuget.
My error: "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyProjectName'"

**What I did:**
I installed MVVMLIGHT 5.4.1.1 via nuget on a computer with a connection to internet (from https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/) with all dependencies and moved the package to an OFFLINE computer.
open UWP project -> right click on References -> Manage NuGet Package -> change to my package source folder -> Browse -> trying to install without success.

I installed the same package via nuget on 2 different computers:
The first one has Windows 10 Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.592) and the second one has Windows 10 Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.1540).
Both have Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.18362.1.

Tried to access Manage NuGet package setting -> General -> Clear All NuGet Cahche(s) and install again.
Tried to open WPF project and install the same package and succeeded without any errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you restore the solution successfully before install the nuget package(right click the solution -> Restore the Nuget Packages)?

Comment: Tried now to restore before insall the nuget package and it says "All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.". Then I tried to install and the result was the same error. @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: I tried above with VS 2017 and it could install nuget package offline. could your test with another nuget package?

Comment: Tried with few packages. Your computer has access to internet? @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: I test with offline scenario. But I could not reproduce this issue.

Comment: Could you test this with other offline computer, I suppose there are some issue in VisualStudio.